# By using the Chain Rule, find d$g(u_0,v_0)$ where $f(x,y) = x^2 + xy - y^2$ and $g(u,v) = f(u^2,uv)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

By using the Chain Rule, find d$g(u_0,v_0)$ where $f(x,y) = x^2 + xy - y^2$ and $g(u,v) = f(u^2,uv)$.

$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ and $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

**My Thoughts**

So I understand that $g(u,v) = (u^2)^2 + (u^2)(uv) - (uv)^2 = u^4 + u^3v - u^2v^2$

Am I simply just trying to get that

d$_ug(u_0,v_0) = 4u_0^3 + 3u_0^2v_0 - 2u_0v_0^2$

and

d$_vg(u_0,v_0) = u_0^3 - 2u_0^2v_0$

That seems to easy to me which makes me think that this isn't correct. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Yea I believe the function is correct, but now I am a little stuck finding du and dv...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $g(u,v)=f\left(x(u,v),y(u,v)\right)$ where
$$x(u,v)=u^2$$and
$$y(u,v)=uv$$

So,  $$dg=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\frac {\partial x}{\partial u} du+\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\frac {\partial x}{\partial v} dv+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\frac {\partial y}{\partial u} du+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\frac {\partial y}{\partial v} dv$$We have the following
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+y=2u^2+uv$$
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}=x-2y=u^2-2uv$$
and
$$\frac {\partial x}{\partial u}=2u$$
$$\frac {\partial y}{\partial u}=v$$
$$\frac {\partial x}{\partial v}=0$$
$$\frac {\partial y}{\partial v}=u$$

So, one only needs to put everything together to obtain the differential $dg$!

Comment: Find du and dv and you'll have the differential after you plug in $(u_0,v_0)$

Comment: Dang,beat me to it.I'm too slow on here.........

Comment: It's better you took his answer anyway-I was trying to express u and v as functions of x and y and you can imagine,that didn't exactly produce nice expressions.Why do I always do things the hard way?